# HTML parsing in Codename One without having to use the XML Parser

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, codenameone

I need to parse a Website using Codename One. There is a class named HTMLParser (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/html/HTMLParser.html) but it does not seem to work. At least I can't get it to run.

As an alternative I tried to use the XML Parser which gladly worked. But while parsing HTML with it I experienced problems concerning non XHTML conform tags like breaks (br). They malform my HTML and thus I can't parse it predictable.

Is there any way to get the HTML Parser to work or some other way to do it?

**EDIT:**
I've chosen to write a Servlet doing the parsing work for me using JSoup. Seems to be a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTMLParser` class was used by the deprecated `HTMLComponent`. It should have been deprecated too asit is useless without it.

`XMLParser` includes all the HTML parsing functionality built into Codename One. It should work with non-conforming `br` tags as well, it might be inconsistent for things like self closing tags vs. open tags but it should still allow you to implement most such use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I had a case where parsing a website was utterly inconsistent and I could not go on further with it. That's why I switched over to a servlet.

Comment: Another option would be to port something like jsoup. This is non-trivial but probably doable.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but was put off by the 450 errors eclipse was reporting. They were mainly due to the missing Regex from Java SE. But since Codename One has got the RE as solution for that you're totally right!

Comment: Yes that would require some work to fix and make more efficient. Regex on JavaSE is super fast but on Codename One it's very slow by comparison. Anyway, if you do choose to take this route and need something in the RE lib you can add it there via a pull request to the Codename One project